# Why am I getting "POST requests are not supported" in my Asp.Net Core log?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 API setup. I also have a few Razor pages that use static content. I am using JWT for authentication. In my `UserController` I have an action stub where I am *developing* a change password action:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("ChangePassword")]
    public IActionResult ChangePassword([FromBody] string password)
    {
        HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("User", out var user);

        _logger.ForContext<UsersController>().Debug("User {EmailAddress} tried to change his password to {Password}.", ((User)user).EmailAddress, password);

        return Ok();
    }
```

This works and logs as tested with Swagger. I have other POST actions. This is the first time I try to get the user with `HttpContext`.

However, only with this new Action, I get in my log two entries:

> 23 Jul 2021 21:36:24.612 POST requests are not supported
> 23 Jul 2021 21:36:24.605 POST requests are not supported

The log (Seq) shows the `SourceContext` is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware`.

I am wonder why I am getting these two log entries and can I safely ignore them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That log entry is [coming from `StaticFileMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/56d80d44ac7dae3048de73b4400378514318a69e/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFileMiddleware.cs#L76-L79) checking if it should take over the request and return a file response.

```cs
public class StaticFileMiddleware
{
    // ...
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!ValidateNoEndpoint(context))
        {
            _logger.EndpointMatched();
        }
        else if (!ValidateMethod(context))
        {
            //  "POST requests are not supported"
            _logger.RequestMethodNotSupported(context.Request.Method);
        }
        else if (!ValidatePath(context, _matchUrl, out var subPath))
        {
            _logger.PathMismatch(subPath);
        }
        else if (!LookupContentType(_contentTypeProvider, _options, subPath, out var contentType))
        {
            _logger.FileTypeNotSupported(subPath);
        }
        else
        {
            // If we get here, we can try to serve the file
            return TryServeStaticFile(context, contentType, subPath);
        }

        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

Since it doesn't serve a static file, it calls the next middleware in the chain, which eventually lets the request be dispatched to your controller.

You can safely ignore it. It's logged at `Debug` level and only matters if you're having problems with static files.